# Java API для Wacom STU 300

Tags: java

На сайте производителя упоминается существование некоего мифического JAVA API для этого агрегата. Но не нашел. Никто не сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендуется ткнуть [сюда](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/docs/WacomWindevFAQ.html) и почитать FAQ - там есть ссыла где скачать Java API.

Comment: жаль только зарегистрироваться там нельзя самостоятельно